# docker compose and .env file usage

Tags: docker-compose, .env

I'm writing a Django project and I have to write a docker compose file for that and also I have a .env file shall I use both of them or how can I use these files for example how can I access my secrert_key in .env file in docker compose

I couldn't do anything I want to access my secrete key but I don't know I have to write it in docker compose or .env